# Errors with indexing when using numpy delete and enumerate

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, numpy-ndarray

Python 3.9

I have a numpy ndarray of strings. The actual array has thousands of strings, but let's say:

```
words_master = ['CARES' 'BARES' 'CANES' 'TARES' 'PARES' 'BANES' 'BALES' 'CORES' 'BORES'
 'MARES']
```

I am trying to create a function that returns a list where the strings containing a given character have been deleted. This works as a while loop and if statement:

```
                index = 0
                temp = []
                while index != len(words_master):
                    idx = words_master[index]
                    if 'A' in idx:
                        temp.append(index)
                    index += 1
                words_master = np.delete(words_master, temp)
```

Since this is still a for loop and if statement, I'm wondering if it can be made more efficient using a list comprehension.

My best guess at this would be:

```
words_master = np.delete(words_master, np.argwhere([x for x, item in enumerate(words_master) if 'A' in item]))
```

Logic here is that np.delete will take the initial array and then delete all items at the indexes set by np.argwhere. However, it gives this output:

```
['CARES' 'BORES' 'MARES']
```

It appears that it ignores the first and last elements?

Other oddities: if I use 'CARES' in item, it returns the list without making any changes:

```
['CARES' 'BARES' 'CANES' 'TARES' 'PARES' 'BANES' 'BALES' 'CORES' 'BORES'
 'MARES']
```

And if I use any other parameter ('MARES' or 'M' or 'O') it seems to return the full list without the first word:

```
['BARES' 'CANES' 'TARES' 'PARES' 'BANES' 'BALES' 'CORES' 'BORES' 'MARES']
```

I tried:

- Playing around with the index, for instance using (reversed(list(enumerate.. or making the list of indices -1. However, these result in the same type of patterns but just displaced.
- Using np.where() instead, but am having similar problems.

I'm wondering if there is a clean way to fix that? Or is the while loop/if statement the best bet?

Edit: to the question "why not use list", I read that numpy arrays are a lot faster than python lists, and when I tested this same for-loop except using a python list with the remove() function, it was 10x slower on a larger dataset.

Comment: Why array?  why not a list?

Comment: You *should not* delete elements of an array/list while you are iterating it, unless you know what you are doing. You should create a new, separate array/list which contains the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `argwhere` returns indices where the `enumerate` is nonzero.  That's not what you want.

```
In [241]: [x for x, item in enumerate(words_master) if 'A' in item]
Out[241]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
In [242]: np.argwhere(_)
Out[242]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7]])
```

Without it the `enumerate` works just fine:

```
In [247]: np.delete(words_master, [x for x, item in enumerate(words_master) if
     ...: 'A' in item])
Out[247]: array(['CORES', 'BORES'], dtype='<U5')
```

But compare its time with a pure comprehension:

```
In [248]: timeit np.delete(words_master, [x for x, item in enumerate(words_master) if 'A' in item])
27.8 µs ± 930 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [249]: timeit [word for word in words_master if word.find('A')==-1]
1.73 µs ± 16.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [251]: timeit [word for word in words_master if 'A' not in word]
604 ns ± 2.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The enumerate part of the `delete` times about the same as the other comprehensions.  So most of the time in [248] is the `delete`.  While an array function, it isn't super fast.  It may scale better than the comprehensions, but we still haven't gotten rid of those.

```
In [252]: timeit [x for x, item in enumerate(words_master) if 'A' in item]
1.06 µs ± 4.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

If we start with an array of strings (instead of the list), ts faster to index it directly, rather than go through `delete`:

```
In [279]: arr = np.array(words_master)
In [280]: arr[['A' not in word for word in arr]]
Out[280]: array(['CORES', 'BORES'], dtype='<U5')
In [281]: timeit arr[['A' not in word for word in arr]]
12.9 µs ± 480 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But we can improve on it by using both the array, and list (for the iteration):

```
In [282]: timeit arr[['A' not in word for word in words_master]]
6.27 µs ± 245 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

words_master = np.array(['CARES', 'BARES', 'CANES', 'TARES', 'PARES', 'BANES', 'BALES', 'CORES', 'BORES', 'MARES']
```

Yes. This can be more clearly written as a list comprehension for boolean indexing.

```
bad_char = "A"
words_without_char = words_master[[bad_char not in x for x in words_master]]

>>> words_without_char
array(['CORES', 'BORES'], dtype='<U5')
```

Could also make a list directly:

```
>>> [x for x in words_master if bad_char not in x]
['CORES', 'BORES']
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried string methods?

```
filtered_words_master = [x for x in words_master if x.find('A') != 1]
Something like this?
```

**EDIT**
Trying to address the issue about arrays vs. lists:

```
def filtering_arrays(arr, substring):
  """ Remove elements containing specific substring """
  return np.delete(arr, [i for i, item in enumerate(arr) if item.find(substring) == 1])
```

Comment: @hpaulj and FillippeOGoncalves I read that numpy arrays are a lot faster than python lists, and when I tested this same for-loop except using a python list with the remove() function, it was 10x slower on a larger dataset. I updated my original question with this caveat, but let me know if I'm off base

Comment: I don't know if I understand the point, but I edited the question to see if it addresses the problem

Comment: Arrays can be faster if used right. But used iteratively and with strings they probably aren't.

Comment: I agree (and still cannot see a while loop on strings being 10x faster than a list comprehension)

Comment: @FilippeO.Gonçalves and hpaulj you are right! I meant that my while loop list solution using remove() was slower. However, I just ran 5,000 trials using equivalent comprehensions for the list and the array, and they were very similar, within 0.01 seconds of each other on this particular set.

Comment: Did you compare while and for loop? Maybe there's still room for improvement

Answer (score 1):

You asked for numpy, here is a numpy one line solution:

```
import numpy as np
words_master = np.array(['CARES','BARES','CANES','TARES','PARES','BANES','BALES','CORES','BORES','MARES'])

words_without_char=words_master[np.char.find(words_master,"A")==-1]
```

If the find command does not find the char, it returns -1, and only those items are returned